# jQuery Change Value of ASP.NET AJAX CascadingDropDown

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, cascadingdropdown

I can use jQuery to change the value of a CascadingDropDown, but the event that fires which causes the target control's child dropdown to populate with data never happens:

```
$("#<%= ddlFromCompetition.ClientID %>").change(function() {
  var fromValue = $("#<%= ddlFromCompetition.ClientID %>").val();
  $("#<%= ddlToCompetition.ClientID %>").val(fromValue); // causes value to change, but child doesn't update
});
```

To be clear, `ddlFromCompetition` and `ddlToCompetition` are not parent/child. It's the child of `ddlToCompetition` that does not update using the above code. When selecting `ddlToCompetition` using the mouse, its child dropdown updates as expected.

I've tried calling `$("#<%= ddlToCompetition.ClientID %>").change()` to try to force the event to fire, but it doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You need the trigger() event

```
$("#<%= ddlToCompetition.ClientID %>").trigger('change');
```

JQuery docs: http://api.jquery.com/trigger/

Also, because the first change event handler for ddlFromCompetition fires in the context of ddlFromCompetition, you should be able to change...

```
var fromValue = $("#<%= ddlFromCompetition.ClientID %>").val();
```

to...

```
var fromValue = $(this).val();
```

Comment: The $(this).val() works (the selected value changes) but not trigger('change'). There must be something peculiar about the ASP.NET AJAX CascadingDropDown behavior and which event it fires that causes it to only respond to a manual change event with the mouse.

Comment: Didn't work. I think I somehow need to call CascadingDropDown.raiseSelectionChanged()

Comment: One other thing to try is to change all of the $ symbols to jQuery, i.e. jQuery("#<%= ddlToCompetition.ClientID %>").trigger('change');
unless you have already called jQuery.noConflict(); earlier on
See this: http://docs.jquery.com/Using_jQuery_with_Other_Libraries